# Why am I getting a syntax error when setting variables in MySQL 5.6?

Tags: mysql, variables, syntax-error, mysql-5.6

I have tried the following:

```
use my_db;

SET SESSION query_cache_type=OFF;

SET @CA_FR_ID = '16';
SET @CA_EN_ID = '15';
SET @US_ID = '1';

select * from my_table where my_table.id in (@CA_FR_ID, @CA_EN_ID);
```

and...

```
use my_db;

SET @CA_FR_ID = '16';
SET @CA_EN_ID = '15';
SET @US_ID = '1';

select * from my_table where my_table.id in (@CA_FR_ID, @CA_EN_ID);
```

and...

```
use my_db;

SET @CA_FR_ID := '16';
SET @CA_EN_ID := '15';
SET @US_ID := '1';

select * from my_table where my_table.id in (@CA_FR_ID, @CA_EN_ID);
```

and...

```
use my_db;

SET @CA_FR_ID = '16',
    @CA_EN_ID = '15',
    @US_ID = '1';

select * from my_table where my_table.id in (@CA_FR_ID, @CA_EN_ID);
```

Each of these results in an error thrown after the first semicolon after `SET`:

> [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET

This is strange because I have used this syntax before. And, even copying/pasting working code from the past is now returning this error.

**EDIT:**

I suppose I must have corrupt a MySQL setting in an earlier variable set attempt. Restarting MySQL allowed me to execute the queries in my above examples.

Comment: What are you attempting to run this through? Most APIs only allow one statement per execute.

Comment: Yes this does not seam to have errors in MySQL. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/340e01/619

Comment: I am executing these via PHPStorm (IDE). I must have corrupt a setting because a server restart allowed these commands to execute as expected.

Comment: Did you change `DELIMITER` during your session by some chance?

Comment: No, because multiple selects delimited with ; continued to work.